# Place list in line with search datatables

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i place the drop down list on the same line with search? 
It is looking like in the following picture now. [image]

The DOM property of the datatable is defined as follows: `dom: '<"#dropDownList">frtlip'`

For the list i used bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: are you using any framework to do your datatable ?

Comment: i use bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need a specific style, but I recommend this :

https://datatables.net/download/index

You just need to use JQuery with it, it provides style for Bootstrap, and you can overwrite it with your own style

Comment: How to use this?

Comment: you can import it just like you imported bootstrap, by using a link in a <script> element, and the style with a <link> element, but don't forget to import JQuery first. You can download it too, and then use a relative path to get it. Check the documentation, all is specified in the website

Comment: Thanks, but his is not helping me